# selenium manager не находит webdriver от chrome на версии selenium(4.16) (python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, webdriver

при запуске строчки
`driver = webdriver.chrome()`
вылазит ряд ошибок

вот элементы кода:
'''
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import pyscreenshot
import win32com.client
import pyautogui

```
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')

f = []
for _ in range(10):
    b = input().split()
    f.append(b[1])
for i in f:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(i)
    # time.sleep(5)
    login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//[@id="quick_login"]/button[1]').click()
    # time.sleep(5)
    num = driver.find_element(By.ID, "index_email").send_keys(name)
    time.sleep(3)
    log = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//[@id="content"]/div[1]/form/button/span').click()
    time.sleep(3)
```

'''
вылазят следующие ошибки:
'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 137, in run
output = json.loads(stdout)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\json_*init*_.py", line 346, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 103, in driver_location
    output = self.run(args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 140, in run
    raise WebDriverException(f"Unsuccessful command executed: {command}") from err
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unsuccessful command executed: C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\windows\selenium-manager.exe --browser chrome --output json


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aleksandr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject7\hui.py", line 18, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 41, in get_path
    raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
```

'''